# How do i calculate the mean from data read in a file

Tags: java, math, mean

I'm trying obtain all the names from one file and all the attendances from another then calculate the average attendance. I know the `att` bit in the calculation is completely wrong but I could not work it out.

```
{
    ArrayList<Match> ourList = new ArrayList(teams);


    ArrayList<Match> teamsAttendance = new ArrayList<Match>();
    for (Match att : ourList)
    {
        if (att != null && att.getTeamName().equals(team.getName()))
        {
            teamsAttendance.add(att);
        }
    }

    double attendance = 0; //start attendance as 0
    for (int i = 0; i < att.length; i++)
    {
      attendance += att[i];  
    }
    return attendance / att.length;
}
```

Comment: Can you post information about the `att` array? And what is your current problem with this code?

Comment: Rather than give you the answer, I woud like you help you figure it out. Why do you say *the `att` bit in the calculation is completely wrong*? Does it fail to compile? If so, what is the error message from the compiler?

Comment: Does your code compile? It seems like `att` is a `Match` instance but you are trying to add it to a `double`

Comment: Maybe you should just count every occurence of team.getName() and divide by teamAttendance.size() casting all those values to double

Comment: @Tom att is what i thought would be the new name for the created array of attendances which is taken from the file

Comment: @dsh I'm pretty certain that att was not supposed to be there in the calculation however i just put it there while i tried to get my head around the problem.

Comment: @Jib'z would you say that is a better solution?

Comment: @RichKid in the code you posted, `att` is an undefined name.  It is not declared anywhere, and so won't compile.  The *other* `att` is a local variable in the loop and so doesn't exist outside the loop (and is an instance of Match, not an array).

Comment: @RichKid the code you posted lacks of explaination and so with the information you gave, assuming ´ourList´ contains all matches and that you are looking for a single team that's what I would do. But I'd divide by ´ourList.size()´ not the ôter one what I told you before

Comment: @dsh  I was trying to use a piece of code i found as a guideline but i could not work out how to incorporate it into my piece of code. 'public static double mean(double[] m) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        sum += m[i];
    }
    return sum / m.length;
}'

Comment: @Jib'z i think that sounds like what i was trying to achieve, could you produce and example of this as i am really struggling to fully get my head around all of this.

Comment: @Jib'z sorry for the lack of an explanation. The file has various team names and the other file has attendances for the matches. I am trying to write a piece of code that finds the average attendance for each team

Comment: This is basic math : count all occurence u want and divide by the total. I can't explain it better

Comment: @RichKid the code you added in a comment is correct as it was presented: it averages a collection of numbers;  you need to figure out how your data structure can become a collection of numbers in order to do the math. It can't be directly copied because you don't have the numbers, yet, to do the math and we don't have an understanding of your data and what you are actually trying to compute.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the Match class will have a team name and attendance(an array list). Just like getting the team name, there should be a get to get the attendance array list .Assuming this you can try the below approach:

```
{
    ArrayList<Match> ourList = new ArrayList(teams);


    ArrayList<Match> teamsAttendance = new ArrayList<Match>();

    //to store the attendance mean for each team
    ArrayList<double> teamAttendanceMean = new ArrayList<double>();

    //to store the attendance values of team
    ArrayList<double> tempAttendance= new ArrayList<double>();



    //declare outside
    double attendance = 0; 

    for (Match att : ourList)
    {
        if (att != null && att.getTeamName().equals(team.getName()))
        {
            teamsAttendance.add(att);
        }
        attendance = 0;// assign 0
        tempAttendance = att.getTeamAttendance();
         for (int i = 0; i < tempAttendance.size(); i++)
         {
              attendance += tempAttendance [i];  
         }             

         //storing the mean value
         teamAttendanceMean.add(attendance/tempAttendance.size());

    }
```

}

Let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong and also post information on the Match class if so.